# Como puedo obtener el valor de una variable de fast-reports

Tags: delphi, delphi-tokyo, fastreport

Estoy trabajando con fast reports y necesito obtener el valor de una variable desde el mismo reporte.

He probado de varias formas como por ejemplo:

```
cant_pag := frxReport1.Variables.Variables['pagina_ant'];
```

De esta forma me obtiene solo el valor inicial de la variable del reporte.

Espero su ayuda.

Desde ya  gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema.
En mi caso de necesitaba extraer la cantidad de paginas que tenia el reporte en cuestión antes de imprimirlo y lo logre de la sgte forma:

```
frxReport1.PrepareReport();
cant_paginas := frxReport1.Report.PreviewPages.Count;
frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
```

De esta forma el reporte se termina con el prepare report y luego se procede a contar la cantidad de paginas para su uso posterior y mostrarlo al usuario.